# Is there a way to reuse babel-loader AST in my own loader?

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I am writing loader for webpack, and I need AST inside it. I already has babel-loader inside my webpack's config. Is there any way to use AST from babel-loader instead of reparsing each file?

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    /* other stuff */
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'my-loader',
                        options: {
                            reuseBabelAst: true
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            ast: true // <-- Something I want from babel-loader
                        } 
                    },
                ],
            }, 
        ]
    },
}
```

```js
// my-loader.js

import traverse from '@babel/traverse';
import { parse } from '@babel/parser';

const loader = async function inlineGetterLoader(content, map, meta) {
    // Something I want
    const ast = meta.babelLoaderAst;

    /* instead of 
    const ast = parse(content, {
        sourceType: "module"
    });
    */

    traverse(ast, {
       CallExpression: myLogic(),
    });

    return;
}
```